# PHP: Why am I getting "Undefined property: myCar::$model"

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP and I am trying to follow a course.

```
<?php 
    class myCar {
        function myCar() {
            $this->model = "Sports";
        }
    }

    $Range_Rover = new myCar();

    echo $Range_Rover->model;
?>
```

According to the tutorial I should get the output "Sports" What is causing the code to result in an error of undefined property?

> Warning: Undefined property: myCar::$model in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\index.php on line 16

[Screenshot of tutorial results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CRQQ.png)

Many thanks,
Stuart

Comment: `function myCar()` is a very old way to write constructors try `function __construct() {             $this->model = "Sports";  }`

Comment: You must be using PHP8 where a method with the name of the class is no longer considered a constructor. Therefore the method `myCar()` is never run by your code. Therefore the propery is never created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct way to do it:

```
<?php 
    class myCar {
        public $model;
        function __construct() {
            $this->model = "Sports";
        }
    }

    $Range_Rover = new myCar();

    echo $Range_Rover->model;
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/bnNrm

***Note: Why above is needed***

a) Defining constructor name as class name is an older practice, and it will give you deprecation message for some php version (php 7 versions).

b) Also from php8 it will be treated like a normal function, not as a constructor, so your purpose will not solve.

Comment: Since php8 function `myCar` is just a function (and __not__ a constructor) and throws no errors/warnings.

Comment: Strictly Deprecation messages are not errors either :)

Comment: Agreed @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the class variable before using it.
Just add "public $model;" before function mycar().

Comment: Not true, if `myCar()` had been run as a constructor (like it would in version of PHP prior to V8) it would have created the property

Answer (score -1):

You should declare model like this

```
public $model;
```

Also as some answers told before, the constructor needs to be defined as `__constructor` now. this would look like

```
<?php 
    class myCar {
        public $model;

        function __constructor() {
            $this->model = "Sports";
        }
    }

    $Range_Rover = new myCar();

    echo $Range_Rover->model;
?>
```

Comment: You are missing that the OP was assuming the `myCar()` would be treated as a constructor. If it had been (<PHP8) that would have created the property